# Python при сохранении объектов в массиве они оказываются одинаковыми

Tags: python

У меня есть такой код, который парсит данные в xml и преобразует их в массив json:

```
def to_json_array(self, data):
    try:
        logging.info("Converting to JSON array...")
        xmlfile = config.wd + "invoice_data"
        with codecs.open(xmlfile, "w", "cp1251") as f:
            f.write(data)
        parsed = untangle.parse(xmlfile)
        result = []

        carData = {}

        for invCarEntry in parsed.getInvoiceReply.invCar:
            if hasattr(invCarEntry, "carNumber"):
                carData['carNumber'] = invCarEntry.carNumber['value']
            else:
                logging.exception("Error: no carNumber")
                return {}

            if hasattr(parsed.getInvoiceReply, "invToStationName"):
                carData['invToStationName'] = parsed.getInvoiceReply.invToStationName['value']
            carData['invToStationCode'] = parsed.getInvoiceReply.invToStationCode['value']
            carData['invRecipName'] = parsed.getInvoiceReply.invRecipName['value']

            result.append(carData)
            logging.info(json.dumps(carData))
        # Создание записей в car_states
        if config.role == "receiver":
            for invCarEntry in parsed.getInvoiceReply.invCar:
                carNumber = invCarEntry.carNumber['value']
                invNumber = parsed.getInvoiceReply.invNumber['value']

        logging.info("Convertation finished")
        return result
    except:
        logging.exception("Exception in to_json_array")
        logging.exception(data)
```

Во время трех итераций формируются разные carData и аппендятся в массив, но почему-то несмотря на то, что `carData` формируются разными, три записи в массиве оказываются одинаковыми, как будто сохраняются не значения `carData`, а ссылки на них. Три записи массива равны последнему сформированному `carData`. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Перемести `carData = {}` под `for invCarEntry in parsed.getInvoiceReply.invCar:`